# For HashMap, is it more efficient to use compute() or put()

Tags: java, hashmap

I have tried looking around for a while but I can't find a concrete answer and still am having some trouble understanding exactly what the `compute` method for `HashMap` does.

The way I understand it at the moment is that `compute` will allow you to manipulate the value but not set it to a new value (like where the garbage collector will have to get rid of the old object) while `put` will just get rid of the old object and set it (like going x = new Something).

If my understanding of this is wrong, please tell me, but regardless, is the `compute` method more efficient in general? Should I use this over `put` whenever possible or is it only used in certain situations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `put` if you want to set a new value unconditionally. Use `compute` if you want to compute a new value based on the existing value in the map. You have the option of either changing it to a new value or removing it from the map.

The [documentation for `compute`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#compute(K,java.util.function.BiFunction)) states that:

> The default implementation is equivalent to performing the following steps for this map:
>
> ```
> V oldValue = map.get(key);
> V newValue = remappingFunction.apply(key, oldValue);
> if (newValue != null) {
>     map.put(key, newValue);
> } else if (oldValue != null || map.containsKey(key)) {
>     map.remove(key);
> }
> return newValue;
> ```

It's more complicated than a simple `put`:

1. It calls `get` to retrieve the current value.
2. It calls the supplied remapping function to convert it to a new value.
3. It either calls `put` to overwrite the old value or `remove` to remove it depending on whether the new value is null or not.

Since ultimately it ends up calling `put`, `compute` has more steps and is slower. If `put` meets your needs—you don't care what's in the map, you just want to set a key to a value—use `put`.

Comment: IMO, compute is not slower.  Neither theoretically, nor implementation wise. In fact the main reason it is promoted and used is because it can do the key lookup once vs. twice as happens in get and put.  I have explained this in https://stackoverflow.com/a/76495979/298742

Comment: The question asks about compute and put, not get and put. I agree that calling compute is better than separate calls to get and put.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

Yes, it is more efficient to use compute, instead of get() and put().

**Longer version**

By using a combination of `compute`, `computeIfPresent` `computeIfAbsent` etc, you can do EXACTLY the same things using compute method as you can do with get and put. *(In fact prior to JDK 8, there was no compute and lambda, but we were all able to "get by" without any large gaping holes in our coding lives, although admittedly, the things got better with lambda.)*

But the main advantages of using compute method is:

1. It is more readable (depends on who is doing the reading, of course)
2. It is atomic - between get and put, things could have changed if you write get and put yourself.
3. It *can be* and is *generally* more efficient.  This is evident from the fact that if you see the source code of HashMap.compute method, you will see
   that it [calls the hash function only once](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/19fb8f93c59dfd791f62d41f332db9e306bc1422/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#L1188-L1251).   The get and put will call
   hash function once each, since the underlying data structure knows
   of those calls as separate calls.  In compute, it knows that the put
   call is "coming", so it can save the hash.  Similarly in other implementations, once the key has been "located", it will be reused, rather than being looked up again.  The main algorithmic cost of this operation is in the lookup, so doing it once is better than doing it twice.

So, between 2 and 3, there are good reasons to use compute.

Comment: Note that the question is about compute vs. put, not compute vs. get + put.

Answer (score 0):

As **@John Kugelman** explained above, **put() is more efficient than compute().**

Apart from explanation, Below are few observations from my side:

There are 2 cases where we can compare set() and compute()

- If key is present in hash map
- If key is not present in hash map

**set(key,value):** If key is not present in hash map, the key with value is added to the hash map and set() method returns "none".

**set(key,value):** If key is present in hash map, the new value will be replaced in place of old value and set() returns "old value".

**compute(key,BiFunction biFunction):** If key is not present in hash map, the key with value is added to to the hash map and compute() method retuns "new value".

**compute(key, BiFunction biFunction):** If key is present in hash map, the new value will be replaced in place of old value and compute() returns "new value"

```
    Map<String,Integer> ss = new HashMap<>(Map.of("A",10,"B",20));
    System.out.println(ss.put("C",30)); // none
    System.out.println(ss); // {A=10, B=20, C=30}

    System.out.println(ss.put("A",11)); // 10
    System.out.println(ss); // {A=11, B=20, C=30}

    System.out.println(ss.compute("D",(x,y)->40)); // 40
    System.out.println(ss); // {D=40, A=11, B=20, C=30}

    System.out.println(ss.compute("B",(x,y)->y+10)); // 30
    System.out.println(ss); // {A=11, B=30, C=30, D=40}
```

- Internally compute() uses set(). The noticeable difference is the method's return types when key is present and not present in hash map
- In terms of efficiency, set() is more efficient than compute().